# Save insert from to file

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, fwrite

I have a input form and want to save the data that I haved insert into a file. Should I use get and set for this? Anyone have any ideas on what I should do?

```js
function myfunction() {
    if (validation()) // Calling Validation Function
    {
        // Serializing Form Data And Displaying It In <p id="wrapper"></p>
        document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = serialize(document.forms[0]); // Serialize Form Data
        document.getElementById("form").reset(); // Reset Form Fields
    }
}

function validation() {
    var name = document.getElementById("namn").value;
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
        <title>Write</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://form-serialize.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/serialize-0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- For Serialization Function -->
        <script src="hej.js"></script> <!-- Include JavaScript File Here-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="login">
                <hr/>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="fill in your name"/><br /><br />
                    <label>Number :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" required="required" placeholder="0876856"/><br/><br />
                    <input onclick="myfunction()" type="submit"id= "submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your PHP part of the code?

Comment: you have no "namn" id for one thing. If you have no php for this, then remove the tag. You've been asked to post the code for it. I for one won't be staying as long as others. Waiting is a waste of my time and not posting full code is also a waste of YOUR time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the normal [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php) you can access the data over $_POST and write it with [fopen](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php), [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fwrite.php) to a file. Over ajax you have to send the Data to a PHP File and do the same there. You cant access the local filesystem over Javascript.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST){

// reformat your data here and format it
$yourDataToWriteInTheData = $_POST['firstname'] . '|' . $_POST['lastname'] . PHP_EOF;
// Open the file (or create it, read the fopen manual)
$fileHandler = fopen('file1.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fileHandler, $yourDataToWriteInTheData);
fclose($fileHandler);
}
```

Comment: Actually you can if you are using IE (ActiveXObject) ^^